# Cant fill username with selenium on java site

Tags: java, selenium

a have a problem with fill username on site with selenium webdriver in java. I cant find login box on selenium.

webdriver.findelement(By.Id("Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username").sendKeys("aaa"); dosent work.

```
   <input name="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username"id="Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username" label="User name" value="" onchange="if (EventHandlers.valueChanged(event, this)==false) return false;" onkeydown="DHTML.cancelBubbleIfNoAltKeyOrEnter();" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;" delayonchange="false" class="textBox" style="text-align: left" size="20" onfocus="EventHandlers.onFocus(event)" onblur="EventHandlers.onBlur(event)" contenteditable="true" type="text">
```

Comment: I am unsure is the copy-paste issue but there is space missing after name field value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is inside `<frame>` tag, you need to switch to it first

```
driver.switchTo().frame("top_frame"); // switch by ID or name
webdriver.findelement(By.Id("Login:LoginScreen:LoginDV:username").sendKeys("aaa");
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

By the way, in Java it should be `By.id`, not `By.Id`

Comment: I try that, dosent work. I need to login on this site https://everest.pzu.pl/pc/PolicyCenter.do

Comment: Console says : 
        at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/BOGU~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4987712503536349862webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10723)
 at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/BOGU~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4987712503536349862webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10732)